# FFMpeg nVidia Pascal best output quality

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-settings

It has taken me weeks to achieve my goal of maximum quality output with different resolutions.

My source file is a video based on 8k (7680x3840), DNxHR HQX, YUV 4:2:2. (master tape)

My hardware is 2xNVIDIA P6000 24, SLI, and Intel Core i9 UHD Graphics 770 Controller. The target files have resolutions of 2, 4, 5 and 8k (Tablets, VR glasses).

Here is my setup for ffmpeg. Does anyone else have a suggestion that I can get even more quality out of the target files?

`ffmpeg -y -threads 8 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "%_infile%" -c:v hevc_nvenc -profile:v main10 -pix_fmt p010le -rc:v:0 vbr -tune hq -tier high -rc-lookahead 90 -no-scenecut 1 -b_adapt 0 -weighted_pred 1 -cq %_constQual% -qmin 1 -qmax 24 -preset p7 -vf scale=%_scale% -b:v %_stdbr% -maxrate:v %_maxbr% -bufsize:v %_maxbr% -movflags faststart -gpu 1 -threads 4 -c:a copy "%_outfile%.mp4"`

Comment: Do you have specific issues with your current output that you have not yet found a solution to?

Comment: Yes, in part. On different tablets, the videos do not run without interference (e.g. stuttering). In the VR glasses, the bandwidth must be greatly reduced in order to avoid shaking in the pan when panning. Controlling the quality of the output only by bandwidth can probably be done better. That's my approach.

Comment: I want to try to achieve the best possible quality for the target devices.

Comment: Then you need to look at the specs of each target device and tune your output for that. You have not provided the target device info, and asking for "best possible" quickly gets into opinion range. I suggest removing references to that in your question. Instead, give us what I had to ask questions to get: the target devices, and what's not working. Use the EDIT button to fix your question and do not add further information in comments.